# core data app crash when adding more than 5 related objects

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, option-type, relationships

I have two core data entities, each with a to-many relationship to the other. I'm using a `tableView` to allow users to select which wageClasses are related to a given Proposal. The project is Swift 3, iOS 10.2.1, and I'm using the `NSManagedObject` subClasses from the Editor menu.

This all works great, until I try to add a sixth wageClass to a Proposal. ***Note: If I try to add any value other than the first 5 into the WageClass array, it crashes. But when I print the array it prints as many values as there are in the array.*** The app crashes with the error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

I also get a Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT error, but the Breakpoints navigator and lldb  list no breakpoints.

I've tested this by trying to add the wageClasses individually, by adding them in different orders, and by creating up to ten wageClasses (to see if it was an issue with the last created wageClass not loading in the `tableView`) but no luck, I get the same result.

Here's where I'm adding:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddWageClassCell", for: indexPath)

    let wageClass = wageClasses[indexPath.row]


    let wageClassStatus = wageClass.value(forKey: "checked") as? Bool ?? true

    cell.textLabel?.text = wageClass.value(forKey: "wageClassName") as? String

    var accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
    var tintColor = UIColor.clear

    if (wageClassStatus) {
        accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
        tintColor = UIColor.green

    }

    cell.accessoryType=accessoryType
    cell.tintColor = tintColor


    return cell

}

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {


        let wageClassObject = self.wageClasses[indexPath.row]

        var wageClassStatus = wageClassObject.value(forKey: "checked") as? Bool ?? false

        wageClassObject.setValue(!wageClassStatus, forKey:"checked")





        proposalToEdit?.addToWageClasses(wageClassObject)




        do {
            try 
            ad.saveContext()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Cannot save object: \(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath,animated:false)

        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)






    }
```

Thanks for your comments!

Comment: The system tells you something like this: " You have an optional ' ? ' value and that's returns as ' nil '. The ' nil ' is actually nothing. You're must be unwrapping it ' ! '.

Comment: Any idea why it lets me add the first five without complaint? Why is it only the sixth that it finds to be nil?

Comment: The same type of codes are works before? Why do you need a six of them? I mean relationships. You've a six table view controller?

Comment: On what line of code does the crash occur? Can you show your cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: I'm adding related objects, not relationships. A proposal can have hundreds of wageClasses, and a wageClass can be used in hundreds of proposals. The crash occurs at ad.saveContext() - but no crash the first five times I add a related object. I added the cellForRowAt IndexPath to the original question.

Comment: Usually when I get odd core data crashes, it's b/c of threads.  Just for giggles, does your crash go away if you wrap the save call inside an ad.performAndWait block?

Comment: I'm searching for ways to implement that, but mostly getting an error that AppDelegate has no member performAndWait

Comment: I was able to run it with performAndWait (see updated code) but everything crashes when I try to add the 6th object, as usual. I know the 6th object isn't nil because I'm seeding 6 wageClass records. I made some updates to the description of the error messages above as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally realized that I was force unwrapping a variable when I formatted a cell with `wageClasses` on a separate tableView on a separate xib. When I wrapped that in an if let statement

```
  if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? WageCell {
                 configureCell(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath)
            } else {
                print("something is nil")
            }

            }
```

the crash went away.